# Django templates: Convert float to integer if it ends with .0?

Tags: django, django-templates

In a Django template, is there a way to convert a float into an integer if and only if it ends in .0?

I have a field for population that is a float in my database. Sometimes it is 'really' a float, ending .5, but more often it ends .0, because there is a whole number of people, and in those cases I'd rather just show an integer.

```
{{ place.population }} people
```

Any ideas for a clever way to get round this in Django?

Comment: Sounds like something that you would have to do in a custom filter.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use the [floatformat filter](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#floatformat) with a negative argument!

Comment: From the documentation: "Using floatformat with no argument is equivalent to using floatformat with an argument of -1."

Comment: Note: This will round values with more decimal places than the given negative argument!

Answer (score 2):

You could write a template tag, but I'd recommend making this a method on your model.

```
class Country(models.Model):

    ...

    def get_population(self):
        if self.population == int(self.population):
            self.population = int(self.population)
        return self.population
```

Then in your template, instead of

```
{{ obj.population }}
```

You would use this:

```
{{ obj.get_population }}
```