# Remove the decimal part of a floating-point number in django?

Tags: python, django, templates

I have a variable called `{{value.item_total }}` which is `499.00`, but I want to remove the decimal points for this value in my templates file to make it `499`. How could I do this?

Comment: You want to remove what?

Comment: I WANT ONLY 499 VALUE....REMOVE DECIMAL AND AFTER DECIMAL ALL DEIGIT

Comment: Oh, please unpress your caps lock...

Comment: ok i have already unpress

Comment: format it..............

Comment: @JérémieAstori For a moment I thought he'll come to say "THANK YOU, IT'S MUCH MORE EASIER TO TYPE NOW"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565876/django-templates-convert-float-to-integer-if-it-ends-with-0):

> You can use the [floatformat filter](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#floatformat) with a negative argument!

The answer would be:

```
{{ value.item_total|floatformat }}
```

Answer (score 10):

you have to use Built-in template tags and filters (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#get-digit). In your case use

```
{{ value.item_total|floatformat:"0" }}
```

Thats it.

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

```
 {{value.item_total|floatformat }}
```